# React; accessing fields within an Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

this is my first question, i hope this is ok:
i am learning about react, and currently am trying to extract weather data from an API. I can save the data in a state without problems, and can access the first object layer without problems too. But the data i need is in the thirs layer `(data -> main -> temp)`, and i get an undefined error when trying to access main.temp

```
showing "main" on the consoles gives me this: 
humidity: 87
pressure: 1017
temp: 285.81
temp_max: 287.04
temp_min: 284.26
```

but I somehow cannot access the fields within.
Here is my code that still works:

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class alex extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      daten: []
    };
    this.tempConverter = this.tempConverter.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get(
        `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&APPID=436238e5e5563aff959aff1d8acc8e32`
      )
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({ daten: res.data });
      });
  }

  tempConverter() {
    const data = this.state.daten.main;
    console.log(data);
  }

  render() {
    return <div>Current Temperatur: {this.tempConverter()}</div>;
  }
}

export default alex;
```

when trying to access data.temp in the convertTemp() function i get **TypeError: Cannot read property 'temp' of undefined**

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set initial state value to null, and only if it is not null I called tempConverter.

```
import axios from "axios";
import React from "react";

class alex extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      daten: null
    };
    this.tempConverter = this.tempConverter.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get(
        `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&APPID=436238e5e5563aff959aff1d8acc8e32`
      )
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({ daten: res.data });
      });
  }

  tempConverter() {
    const data = this.state.daten.main;
    console.log(data.temp); // 286.63
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>Current Temperatur: {this.state.daten && this.tempConverter()}</div>
    );
  }
}
export default alex;
```

sample codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-fog-dubzb

Answer (score 1):

Your `daten` property in state is initialized to empty array, there is not any property `main`. Maybe after you get the response from async call. But for the first render is it just empty array.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of API request isn't completed yet, when you call `{this.tempConverter()}`.

Therefore you should call `this.tempConverter()`, once your data is already fetched (and may having a Loading indicator).

```
render() {
    // Show a Loading, if the data isn't fetched yet
    if (!this.state.daten.main) return '<div>Loading ...</div>';

    // Here, you're sure you have the data, so you can render it
    return <div>Current Temperatur: {this.tempConverter()}</div>
}
```

Comment: thanks, but i don't think i understand what you mean. the fetch must be completed when tempconverter is called, since i can see the data with console.log
as in: 
`console.log(this.state.daten.main)` works fine, but `console.log(this.state.daten.main.temp)` does not
 does not work

Comment: Nope. Fetch may not be completed because it's an async call. So there is a case, you call `this.tempConverter()`, and you don't still have the API response.

Comment: I've updated my answer, you can check the comments. Thanks!